# Calling in templates the right way

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I see many different answers on stackoverflow and you must forgive me as I've never worked with this kind of stuff before nodejs/ejs.

I found a dashboard called Argon Dashboard by creativetim. I am trying to get it setup. So far I have the database, files unpacked. Have redis setup everything ready to go. I have created a index.html just as the documents show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

     <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

          <title>Argon Dashboard</title>

          <!-- Favicon -->
          <link href="/assets/img/brand/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">

          <!-- Fonts -->
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Icons -->
          <link href="/assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="/assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Argon CSS -->
          <link type="text/css" href="/assets/css/argon.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>

     <body>


          <!-- Core -->
          <script src="/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

          <!-- Argon JS -->
          <script src="/assets/js/argon.min.js"></script>
     </body>

</html>
```

My problem is I am not sure really how to get started or where to even go to get started. Like I said I tried stack overflow but I can't really piece together what is going on. The documentation for argon doesn't demonstrate calling a template. I suppose it is simple?

Answer (score 0):

Starting it it's simple. Have you got a http server setup ? This runs on a http server. You direct the server to the folder where you have the files, then you call something like `http://localhost:<whatever port you configured in the server>/index.html` . You can even say to the server that index.html is your default page and then you would only call `http://localhost:<whatever port you configured in the server>`.

You can find some examples on how to create an http server on node here:

https://stackabuse.com/how-to-start-a-node-server-examples-with-the-most-popular-frameworks/

After that you can start experimenting with it.

Some excessivly simple examples even run directly without a server. Just open the index.html in any browser.

Specifically with this template I have downloaded it and just clicked index.html and it opened without any problem. If what you want it's just seeing it in you machine, all you have to do is open index.html page in a browser after decompressing the `argon-dashboard-master.zip` file. Just double clicking in it should be enough.

If you need something else, please comment and I'll try to help you further.

Comment: @Sam: that edit you proposed it's not helpful because the OP is using Node, and probably will create a server in it not in Apache/Nginx/whatever, so ports 80 and 443 aren't configured as default.

Comment: @sam also please read SO editing guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing thanks